# Value in dataframe column wont change from string to float

Tags: python, pandas

So I've got a column in a dataframe that is filled with float values and occasional string values. I've tried following some answers on stack but it just doesnt work.

```
print(data['Snowfall'][48609]) #prints #VALUE!
print(type(data['Snowfall'][48609])) #prints <class 'str'>
data['Snowfall'].str.contains("#VALUE!").replace(float(0.0),inplace=True)
print(type(data['Snowfall'][48609])) # prints <class 'str'>
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: You may want `df.astype()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) passing 'coerce' to the `errors` argument.
Then [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to change coerced values to `0`

```
df['Snowfall'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Snowfall'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```